# Adding Columns to Existing Schema

Tags: python, django

I am just getting started with Django (1.8) and I am a bit confused about how to modify my models.

If I go in and add a new field to an existing model, I start getting "No Such Column" error. So far, I've just been wiping my DB and starting over, but that gets annoying, is there a process for this?

What happens when I go to production? How would I modify the schema at that point? All the resources I see online are for South, which I guess is built into this version of django, but still can't find any solid info.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django 1.7+ there is no need of `south`.Only

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If you're changing over from an existing app you made in django 1.7-, then you need to do one pre-step (as I found out) listed in the documentation:

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_label
```

Also try this

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    myfiled = models.CharField()
    # ...

    class Meta:
        managed = True
```

Comment: When I run that, it tells me that there are no changes detected.

Comment: add your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Yup, this is something I've been working on for a week or so already, so not a new project. But every time I add a column I face this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own sql command to add the missing column giving you that error.
first run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

then you can go to your app and find the newly generated migration file
having a code similar to the code below.

I'm not sure the kind of column you want add but inside `operations` in the below code, you put your sql command. In my example I'm just adding a character varying field.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '0002_auto_20150619_2439'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mycolumn character varying(50) NOT NULL')
    ]
```

I hope this helps.